# How does the ReactBootstrap OverlayTrigger container property work?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a popover inside OverlayTrigger.

I define it as

```
const myOverlayTrigger = <ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger 
    placement='bottom' overlay={<ReactBootstrap.Tooltip>...</ReactBootstrap.Tooltip>}>
    {myContent}
  </ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger>;
```

Then I render it inside one of my elements like that:

```
<li>{myOverlayTrigger}</li>
```

I want to render OverlayTrigger itself inside `<li>` but it renders inside body, as defined in documentation. I'm trying to use container attribute to render it inside parent `<li>`.

First, I tried to assign ID to `<li>` and pass this ID as a string to container=... (which isn't a best way).

Second, I tried to create additional element `<span></span>` and render it inside

along with {myOverlayTrigger}. Also I pass it (assigned to variable) to container attribute

```
const c = <span></span>;
... container={c} ...
<li>{c} {myOverlayTrigger}</li>
```

Both approaches consistently gives an error `not a dom element or react component`.

Obviously assigning `<li>...</li>` itself as a container doesn't work either as it being defined *after* myOverlayTrigger is defined.

Question: how to use it right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ReactBootstrap.Overlay` is recommended for the reason listed in the [document](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#overlays).

> The OverlayTrigger component is great for most use cases, but as a
>   higher level abstraction it can lack the flexibility needed to build
>   more nuanced or custom behaviors into your Overlay components. For
>   these cases it can be helpful to forgo the trigger and use the Overlay
>   component directly.

For your case, the code below renders the `ReactBootstrap.Overlay` component into a list item with React `ref` attribute.

```
getInitialState() {
    return (
        show: false
    );
},
render() {
    return (
        <ul>
            <li ref="dest" onClick={ () => {
                this.setState( { show: !this.state.show } );
            }}>my contents</li>
            <ReactBootstrap.Overlay placement="bottom"
                show={ this.state.show } container={ this.refs.dest }>
                <ReactBootstrap.Tooltip>tooltip</ReactBootstrap.Tooltip>
            </ReactBootstrap.Overlay>
        </ul>
    );
}
```

When the tooltip is displayed by clicking, the resulting HTML would be

```
<ul data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1.1.1.1:$3.1.1">
    <li data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1.1.1.1:$3.1.1.0">
        contents
        <div>
            <div role="tooltip" class="fade in tooltip right" data-reactid=".3">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow" data-reactid=".3.0"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner" data-reactid=".3.1">My tooltip</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <span data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1.1.1.1:$3.1.1.1">,</span>
    <noscript data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.0.0.1.1.1.1:$3.1.1.2"></noscript>
</ul>
```

Comment: This answer may need an update. The docs link is broken and I suspect syntax has changed.