# Extend @typings in Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-bootstrap

I am writing a application using React and Typescript
One of the components is using an ReactBootstrap.Overlay trigger, and I would like to use the none supported parameter "shouldUpdatePosition={true}" as argument. 
However that parameter is not defined in the @types for react-bootstrap (and since it is a non-supported argument I guess that is correct)
Is it possible to extend the @types from @types/react-bootstrap with this parameter?

My code looks like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactBootstrap from "react-bootstrap"

export interface IDetailsPopoverProps {
    placement?: string;
}

export class DetailsPopover extends React.Component<IDetailsPopoverProps, any> {
public render(): JSX.Element {
    var detailsPopover = <ReactBootstrap.Popover id={this.props.id} className="details-popover">
                {this.props.children}
    </ReactBootstrap.Popover>;
        return (
            <div className="details-popover-container">
                    <ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger 
                        ref="trigger"
                        container={this} 
                        //This is the parameter which does not exist in @types
                        shouldUpdatePosition={true} 
                        trigger="click" 
                        rootClose placement={this.props.placement ? this.props.placement : "bottom"} 
                        overlay={detailsPopover}>
                        <span className="details-popover-trigger">
                            <b className="caret"></b>
                        </span>
                    </ReactBootstrap.OverlayTrigger>
             </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is in the handbook

Comment: You might be better off using the Overlay component instead of OverlayTrigger https://stackoverflow.com/a/33062126/203371

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like this declaration to your file:

```
declare module "react-bootstrap/lib/OverlayTrigger" {
    interface OverlayTriggerProps {
        shouldUpdatePosition: boolean;
    }
}
```

Here's [the handbook page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) I assume Aluan Haddad was talking about.

Comment: Thank you! It was the name of the module "react-bootstrap/lib/OverlayTrigger", I struggled with.